# Removing element from `LinkedList`

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

folks, my code has to remove a certain element from the list. It has to remove all of the occurences of the list. For example, if I'd like to remove `"3"` and the input is:

```
1
2
3
4
3
5
```

then the output should be:

```
1
2
4
5
```

But my code only removes the last occurence of the element as it can be seen when I run my code:

```
3
4
3
2
1

After removing element 3 


 4
 3
 2
 1
```

Could smb please help me out with that? THanks in advance!

```
public void removeElements(String number){
        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("The list is empty!");
        }
        else{
            if(firstLink.data.equals(number)){
                firstLink = firstLink.next;
            }
            else{
                Link current = firstLink.next;
                Link previous = firstLink;
                while(current != null){
                    if(current.data.equals(number)){
                        previous.next = current.next;
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        previous = current;
                        current = current.next;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop to remove elements is breaking on the first match. Maybe something like the following would work better. When current is a match, update previous.next but leave previous pointing at the previous node, and when it's not a match, update previous to point to the current node.

```
while (current != null) {
    if (current.data.equals(number)) previous.next = current.next;
    else previous = current;
    current = current.next;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, @JohnBickers, but I don't really get when you say "When current is a match, update previous.next but leave previous pointing at the previous node". How should I leave `previous` pointing to `previous`?

Comment: @John, that's referring to the difference between what happens when the if statement is true, vs. what happens when it's false.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `break`, your loop is breaking after it gets into it for the first time.

Another point is, it is falling in your `if(firstLink.data.equals(number))` and completely ignoring the `else` block. You should not have that block in `else`. It should be outside.

```
    if(firstLink.data.equals(number)){
        firstLink = firstLink.next;
    }
    Link current = firstLink.next;
    Link previous = firstLink;
    while(current != null){
       if(current.data.equals(number)){
          previous.next = current.next;
       } else {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
       }
   }
```

Comment: As @John Bickers mentioned, you should not update `previous` when it is a  match.

Comment: Actually, in your case, it is falling in second if condition and not going to else block at all.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is iterate through the entire loop and check if the value of the element matches the searched value. If it does then you can use remove that element. I won't give away the solution to this but I can provide you with the algorithm.

```
for(int i = 0; i < length of list; i++)
{
    if(ith element of the list == value to be removed)
        //remove the ith term using .remove(i) method     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is make a new collection containing all the values you want to remove from the LinkedList, and then call removeAll on the list:

```
ArrayList<String> numbersToRemove = new ArrayList<String>();
numbersToRemove.add("3");

list.removeAll(numbersToRemove);
```

This way, if you want to remove multiple numbers later on, you can just add them to numbersToRemove.

Some of the other answers are a bit simpler and more straightforward, though, so use them if they make sense, like iterating through the list and removing any elements that match the element you are removing. The only problem with this is that you will get a ConcurrentModificationException if you modify the list while iterating through the list using the object : list syntax, and will probably get an index out of range exception if you iterate through it using indices, so you will probably need to do something like this instead:

```
while (list.contains("3")) {
    ll.remove("3");
}
```